# 50k lines into DataTables with json data (text, title, sort)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have to put 50k lines into a table. Server side paging is not possible.

It works fine for simple data:

```
    var tableData = [];
    for ( var i=0 ; i<50000 ; i++ ) {
        tableData.push( [ i,i,i,i ] );
    }
    $(table).DataTable( {
        data: tableData,
        scrollY: 200,
        paging: true
    });
```

But I need it for data like:

```
    for ( var i=0 ; i<50000 ; i++ ) {
        tableData.push( [ 
            { text: i, title: "something", dataSort: something },
            { text: i, title: "something", dataSort: something },
            { text: i, title: "something", dataSort: something },
            { text: i, title: "something", dataSort: something },
        ] );
    }
```

I tried it with the columns and render option but it didn't work.
https://jsfiddle.net/ze69kd8a/

Comment: what dont work?

Comment: the columns are empty

Comment: did you add the columns

Comment: sure https://jsfiddle.net/ze69kd8a/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't set the columns that you need
for example:

```
 $('#example').DataTable( {
     data: data,
     columns: [
         { data: 'text' },
         { data: 'title' },
         { data: 'dataSort' }
     ] } );
```

For more info about that you can read in their documentations [here](https://datatables.net/manual/data/#Objects)

Comment: this should work @ue7m

Comment: its not my answer or question @Seabizkit

Comment: @ShreyanMehta sozs missed ill delete.... sorry, miss read PO

Comment: I tried something around but I'm getting [object Object] https://jsfiddle.net/ze69kd8a/

Comment: Your columns are array in array and dataset wrong, please see this working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/deadlyacid/yck9zgpa/

Comment: @Elad I think you forgot to save your code? Is the same like mine, with the same issue.

Comment: @ue7m, opps my bad.. try now: https://jsfiddle.net/deadlyacid/yck9zgpa/4/

Comment: @Elad it works now, ty :)